# Mahout error with Hadoop2.2

Tags: java, hadoop, mahout

I'm trying to execute a mapreduce job for XML parsing using mahout 0.9 library on Hadoop 2.2.
But I'm getting following error :

```
14/02/24 16:03:02 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1393235568433_0004_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext, but class was expected
14/02/24 16:03:12 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1393235568433_0004_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Error: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext, but class was expected
14/02/24 16:03:31 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1393235568433_0004_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
Error: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext, but class was expected
14/02/24 16:03:53 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
14/02/24 16:03:53 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1393235568433_0004 failed with state     FAILED due to: Task failed task_1393235568433_0004_m_000000
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0
```

I tried to search for solution but got the link http://osdir.com/ml/general/2014-02/msg39414.html , which states that Mahout 0.8 or 0.9 is not supported for Hadoop 2.2.
 Any workaroung possible??

Answer (score 1):

About an hour ago Mahout has officially added support to Hadoop 2.x in the master branch (see [MAHOUT-1329](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAHOUT-1329))

Checkout the code here https://github.com/apache/mahout and recompile using:

```
mvn clean package -Dhadoop2.version=2.2.0
```

Try and see if that works.