# Mahout 0.9 and Hadoop 2.2.0 - Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected

Tags: java, hadoop, mahout

Where did my code go wrong? When I searched, I found a similar post, but couldn't adapt it to my problem.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
    at org.apache.mahout.common.HadoopUtil.getCustomJobName(HadoopUtil.java:174)
    at org.apache.mahout.common.AbstractJob.prepareJob(AbstractJob.java:614)
    at org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.preparation.PreparePreferenceMatrixJob.run(PreparePreferenceMatrixJob.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.item.RecommenderJob.run(RecommenderJob.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.item.RecommenderJob.main(RecommenderJob.java:322)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:152)
    at org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver.main(MahoutDriver.java:195)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

Comment: Using Mac OSX with JDK1.7

Comment: What steps did you follow ? What is your environment like?

Comment: Just trying to run this and getting the above msg.   mahout recommenditembased --input /datasets/ml-100k/u.data-noTS.csv --output output/ --similarityClassname SIMILARITY_COSINE

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue I believe and will be available in Mahout 1.0. If you want support for Hadoop 2.x, you can try re-compiling mahout from trunk.

Fixed in this JIRA ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAHOUT-1329

Also have a look at another similar question: [Mahout error with Hadoop2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985505/mahout-error-with-hadoop2-2)

Comment: Thanks. All set now after getting tar ball of hadoop-1.2.1. Still it's  a mystery how come 2.2.0 worked [downloaded date was Mar 18]. All it says now as below, which is OK. Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

Running on hadoop, using /Users/shota/Downloads/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/hadoop and HADOOP_CONF_DIR=
MAHOUT-JOB: /Users/shota/Downloads/mahout-distribution-0.9/mahout-examples-0.9-job.jar
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

Comment: simply unset HADOOP_HOME, and the warning will go away

Comment: hello @SobhanH please explain how you have solved this problem. I can't get what you have done. what do you mean by getting tar ball of hadoop-1.2.1